# Exact delay in screen draw and keyboard keypress event in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, real-time, time-precision

I am working on a Qt project in which exact time at which certain events occur is of prime importance. To be specific: I have a very simple animation that must be drawn to the screen at certain time say t1. Once I issue the `QWidget` update to start the animation, it will take a small time dt (depending on screen refresh rates etc.) to actually show the update on screen. I need to measure this extra time dt. I am unsure as to how to do it.

I thought of using `QTime` and `QElapsedTimer` object in the paint event of the `QWidget` but I'm not sure if that would achieve my goal.

Similarly, when the user presses a key it will be registered after a small delay based on the polling rate of the keyboard. I need to account for this delay as well. If I could get the polling rate I know on average how much will the delay be.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is--by definition--not possible from within the computer.

How would you expect to be able to tell when a pixel "actually showed up" on the screen, without a sensor stuck to the monitor and synchronized to an atomic clock the computer has access to also?  :-)

The odds are stacked even further against Qt because it's generally used as an abstraction layer on top of Win/OSX/Linux.  Those weren't [Real-Time Operating Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) of any kind in the first place.

All you can know is when you asked for something to happen.  Then you can time how long it takes for you to get back control to make another request.  You can set some expectations on your basic "frame rate" throughput by doing this, but there are countless factors that could lead to wide variations in performance at any moment in time.

If you can dig through to the kernel/driver level you can find out a closer-to-the-metal measure of when the actual effect went to the hardware.  But that's not Qt's domain, and still doesn't tell you the "actual" answer of when the effect manifested in the outside world.

About the best you're going to get out of Qt is a [periodic QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtimer.html#interval-prop).  It can make a callback at (roughly) millisecond resolution.  If that's not good enough... you're going to need a smaller boat.  :-)

You might get a little boost from stuff related to the search term ["high resolution timer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer):

- [Qt high-resolution timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730765/qt-high-resolution-timer)
- http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/31941

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes millisecond accuracy is fine. I understand there is an additional layer of abstraction - So when I'm in the paint event of the `QWidget` will running a high res timer just at the starting of the paint and end of the paint function give an approximate estimate of the time spent in pushing the data to screen.
If I understand correctly the paint command is not always honored, what can i do about that?

Comment: @user3726066 My point was that your understanding of the estimate of time pushing data to the screen--as it is--really comes from the reverse: *start* the timer at the end of one paint call, then *end* it at the beginning of the next.  If you try queueing up a bunch of events in series you can sort-of-characterize the quantity you say you are looking for.  Otherwise you're just timing *your* painting code.  But moreover: it would be easier to address your question if you explained *why* you can't just set a periodic QTimer and let it run.  What is the "bad thing" you want to not happen?

Comment: Ok got it. Let me explain the task at hand that would explain why I have such requirements. Basically it is a reaction time experiment for some studies. A visual input is presented to which the user responds via keyboard or mouse. To be able to find the reaction time precisely I need to know when was the stimulus presented on the screen and when was the key pressed. As monitor refresh rates are very slow (60Hz) the delay is drawing on screen is a bigger issue. Let me know if you have some insights... Thanks..

Comment: Well if it's academic I'd read up on what others are doing--your keywords of "screen refresh" and "keyboard polling" combined with "reaction time experiment" or "cognitive" turns up stuff like [this PDF](http://www.lrdc.pitt.edu/schneider/p2465/Readings/E-Prime%20UsersGuide%20Ch%203.pdf) or [this one](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~ben/papers/Shneiderman1984Response.pdf).  If you want to get serious you could boot up a free [RTOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_real-time_operating_systems) that runs on x86, time it with instruments once, then hardcode that timing in...

Answer (score 0):

> I thought of using `QTime` and `QElapsedTimer` object in the paint event of the `QWidget` but I'm not sure if that would achieve my goal.

This is, in fact, the only way to do it, and is all you can actually do. There is nothing further that can be done without resorting to a real-time operating system, custom drivers, or external hardware.

You may not need both - the `QElapsedTimer` measuring the time passed since the last update is sufficient.

Do note that when the event loop is empty, the delay between invocation of `widget.update()` and the `paintEvent` executing is under a microsecond, assuming that your process wasn't preempted.

> it is a reaction time experiment for some studies. A visual input is presented to which the user responds via keyboard or mouse. To be able to find the reaction time precisely I need to know when was the stimulus presented on the screen and when was the key pressed.

There is essentially only one way of doing it right without resorting to a realtime operating system or a custom driver, and a whole lot of ways of doing it wrong.  So, what's the right way?

A small area of the screen needs to change color or brightness coincidentally with the presentation of the visual stimulus. You attach a fiber optic to the screen, and feed it into a receiver attached to an [external event timer](http://www.mccdaq.com/solutions/USB-Counter-Timer-Solutions.aspx). The contact closure in the keyboard is also fed to the same event timer. This lets you precisely time the latency of the response with no regard for operating system latencies, thread preemption, etc. The event timer can be something as cheap as an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc), if you are willing to do a bit more development work.

If you are showing the stimulus repetitively and need a certain timing between stimulus presentations, you simply repeat the presentation often and collect both response latency and stimulus-to-stimulus timing in your data. You can then discard the presentations that were outside of desired tolerances.

This approach is screen-agnostic and you can use it even on a mobile device, as long as it can somehow interface with your timer hardware. The timer hardware can of course be networked, making interfacing easy.