# Qt microseconds timer implementation

Tags: qt

In Qt all the Classes are  having Milliseconds timer .
I need to implement Microsecond timer using hardware timer or any Qt classes will not support for Microsecond timer.

Any one please help me how to implement microsecond timer in Qt application code?

Comment: You may want to look at this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730765/qt-high-resolution-timer

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you wish to measure time with microsecond resolution, or do you wish to implement delays with such resolution? These would be very different problems.

Answer (score 7):

You should use [QElapsedTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html), wich has nanoseconds precision, as follows:

```
QElapsedTimer timer;
timer.start();

foo();//TODO your stuff

qDebug() << "The foo() function took" << timer.nsecsElapsed() << "nanoseconds";
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so I post answer.

I think you can also use usleep() function from POSIX, just #include < unistd.h >.

Reference on [this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/usleep.html) .

Comment: That's not available under Windows. Does it?

Comment: @jpo38 You're right, but he did not tell us on which platfrom he works.

Comment: As far as I know usleep() is deprecated, new code should use nanosleep() instead.