# QTimer not accurate at all?

Tags: c++, qt

Running on Windows7 64bit machine with a very powerful CPU (8 core 16 threads).
I used a QTimer to trigger a function call at 50Hz.
But I ended up with 30Hz.
The function call itself definitely takes less than 10ms to finish.
The whole process happens in a separate thread.

What could go wrong in my case? The Qt's doc said it will be accurate within 5%?

Comment: `The accuracy of timers depends on the underlying operating system and hardware.` So.. Probably your OS, or hardware doesn't support greater precision.

Comment: On windows 7 x64 I can get very stable and accurate timer triggering every 10 msec, most of the time it is accurate to within 1 msec, that's 100 Hz. If `Qt::PreciseTimer` doesn't get you there, there might be something wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve a better timer precision by setting [timer type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timerType-prop) property to `Qt::PreciseTimer` (the default type is `Qt::CoarseTimer`).

From the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TimerType-enum):

> **`Qt::PreciseTimer`** – Precise timers try to keep millisecond accuracy.
>   **`Qt::CoarseTimer`** – Coarse timers try to keep accuracy within 5% of the desired interval.

However, as pointed out by @Paul and @AlgirdasPreidžius, there is still no guarantee that the precision will be perfectly accurate.

Answer (score 8):

Windows 7 is not RTOS, so there is no guarantee that the timer will fire exactly when you expect it to fire. This is not `QTimer` issue, but the OS.

From `QTimer` documentaion:

> The **accuracy of timers depends on the underlying operating system** and
>   hardware. Most platforms support a resolution of 1 millisecond, though
>   the **accuracy of the timer will not equal this resolution in many
>   real-world situations**. The accuracy also depends on the timer type.
>   For Qt::PreciseTimer, QTimer **will try to keep** the accurance at 1
>   millisecond. Precise timers will also never time out earlier than
>   expected.

Note, that the documentation states "will try to keep" and not "guarantees to keep".

Answer (score 8):

Just to illustrate the issue, I did some quick-and-dirty timing in `PyQt5` on a Windows 7 64-bit system, using `QTimer` both *with* and *without* the high-precision setting.

Here's what the result looks like using *default* precision (as in PyQt4):

[image: requested timer interval vs measured timer interval for default precision]

Dots represent the `median` of 100 samples, vertical lines indicate the range (`min` to `max`). Ideally, all dots would be on the dashed line.

Note the obvious discrepancies between approx. 20ms and 100ms. For example, setting `QTimer` to `20ms` (`50Hz`) in my case results in an actual (measured) interval of approx. 31ms (`32Hz`). Coarse indeed.

And this is what it looks like when using the `PreciseTimer`:

[image: requested timer interval vs measured timer interval for high precision]

Much better, I would say, especially if you are interested in intervals between 20ms and 100 ms.

For those interested, here's the code (undoubtedly it can be much improved):

```
import sys
import time
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot
try:
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
    print 'using PyQt5'
except:
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    print 'using PyQt4'


class StampTimer(QtCore.QTimer):
    signal_quit = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, number_of_samples, precise=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StampTimer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if precise:
            try:
                self.setTimerType(QtCore.Qt.PreciseTimer)
                print 'using precise timer (PyQt5)'
            except:
                print 'precise timer not available (PyQt4)'
        self.number_of_samples = number_of_samples
        self.stamps_ms = []
        self.timeout.connect(self.stamp)

    def start(self):
        self.stamps_ms = []
        super(StampTimer, self).start()

    def stamp(self):
        # Save a timestamp (use clock() instead of time())
        self.stamps_ms.append(1e3 * time.clock())
        # Quit when we reach the specified number of samples
        if len(self.stamps_ms) == self.number_of_samples:
            self.stop()
            self.signal_quit.emit()


try:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
except:
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Parameters
number_of_intervals = 100
intervals_requested_ms = range(1, 10)
intervals_requested_ms.extend(range(10, 60, 2))
intervals_requested_ms.extend(range(60, 200, 10))
intervals_requested_ms.append(1000)

# Variables
intervals_measured_ms = numpy.zeros(
    (number_of_intervals, len(intervals_requested_ms)), float)

# Run
timer = StampTimer(number_of_samples=number_of_intervals+1, precise=False)
timer.signal_quit.connect(app.quit)
for index, interval_requested_ms in enumerate(intervals_requested_ms):
    # For each interval in the list, we run the timer until we obtain 
    # the specified number of samples
    timer.setInterval(interval_requested_ms)
    timer.start()
    app.exec_()
    # Calculate statistics
    intervals_measured_ms[:, index] = numpy.diff(timer.stamps_ms)
    median_ms = numpy.median(intervals_measured_ms[:, index])
    max_ms = numpy.max(intervals_measured_ms[:, index])
    min_ms = numpy.min(intervals_measured_ms[:, index])
    # Add to plot
    print 'requested: {} ms, ' \
          'measured: median(min/max) {:.1f} ({:.2f}/{:.2f}) ms'.format(
        interval_requested_ms, median_ms, min_ms, max_ms)
    pyplot.plot(interval_requested_ms, median_ms, 'ok')
    pyplot.plot([interval_requested_ms]*2, [min_ms, max_ms], '-k')

# Plot result
pyplot.plot([0, 1000], [0, 1000], 'k--')
pyplot.xscale('log', nonposx='clip')
pyplot.yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
pyplot.xlabel('interval requested [ms]')
pyplot.ylabel(
    'interval measured [ms] (median, n={})'.format(number_of_intervals))
pyplot.show()
```

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19103973) for valuable insights.